# hql select attribute null in tables

Tags: hibernate

I have two entities Empleado and Cargo :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "empleado")
public class Empleado  {
 private Integer id;
 private String nombre;
 private String codigo;
 private Cargo cargo;

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq", sequenceName = "empleado_id_seq",allocationSize=1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq")
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "nombre")
public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

@Column(name = "codigo")
public String getCodigo() {
    return codigo;
}

public void setCodigo(String codigo) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_cargo_empresa")
public Cargo getCargo() {
    return cargo;
}

public void setCargo(Cargo cargo) {
    this.cargo = cargo;
}
```

}

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cargo")
public class Cargo implements Serializable {

private Integer id;
private String nombre;
private String descripcion;

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq", sequenceName = "cargo_id_seq",allocationSize=1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq")
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "nombre")
public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

@Column(name = "descripcion")
public String getDescripcion() {
    return descripcion;
}

public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
}
```

and I want to do the following query in hql :

```
@Override
public List<EmpleadoDTO> obtenerLstEmpleado() {
    StringBuilder sbQuery = new StringBuilder();
    sbQuery.append("select new com.consorciojm.rrhh.empleado.util.EmpleadoDTO(");
    sbQuery.append("e.id,e.codigo,e.nombre,e.apellidoPaterno,e.apellidoMaterno,");
    sbQuery.append("e.dni,e.telefono,e.celular,e.cargo.id,e.cargo.nombre) ");
    sbQuery.append("from Empleado e where e.codigo is not null ");
    List<EmpleadoDTO> lstEmpleado = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(sbQuery.toString()).list();
    return lstEmpleado;
}
```

but there are records in Empleado that have null in attribute cargo (id_cargo_empresa = null), so I need that the query return the result with e.cargo.id = null and e.cargo.nombre, in this way I get the records the Empleado with data in cargo or null. The query that I put above doesn't return anything because cargo is null and e.cargo.nombre can not be returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using e.cargo.nombre creates an implicit **inner** join. So it effectively filters out all the empleados with a null cargo. You want a **left** join:

```
select ..., cargo.nombre from from Empleado e 
left koin e.cargo cargo 
where e.codigo is not null
```

Also note that using a StringBuilderto create your query is both less readable, and less efficient than simply concatenating the parts using `+` (the compiler would concatenate the parts and only store the full query in the class, instead of concatenating at runtime).